# Continuity of $x\sin\frac{1}{y}$ at $(x, 0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I need to check if function is continue in $(x,0)$
$$f(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x\sin\frac{1}{y}  & \mbox{if } y \ne 0 \\
  0 & \mbox{if } y = 0
 \end{array}
\right.$$
Can someone help me understand if I approached this correctly?

---

First, I check the following limit

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x,0)} x\sin\frac{1}{y}$$

Which does not exist. I can write it as

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x,0)} x \lim_{(x,y) \to (x,0)} \sin\frac{1}{y}$$

The first limit tends to $x$ itself, the second one diverges.

For $x=0$ the limit

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x\sin\frac{1}{y} = 0$$

Indeed, by the squeeze theorem I can write

$$-1\leq\sin\frac{1}{y} \leq 1 $$ 
$$-x \leq x\sin\frac{1}{y} \leq x$$

Thus reducing the limit to

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} x = 0$$

Thus $f(x,y)$ is continuous  $\{ \forall (x, y) \in \Re^2 \mid x \ne 0 \}$

I'm a beginner, thank you in advance!

Comment: If $x\ne 0$, then in any sufficiently small neighbourhood of $(x,0)$, $f(x,y)$ takes values arbitrarily close to $x$ and $-x$ (because any neighbourhod of $(x,0)$ contains non-zero values of $y$). So $f$ is not continuous at $(x,0)$.

Comment: Correct, I did not add that conclusion in my request. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Now I'm not at all sure what your question is! Can you clarify please?

Comment: Sure, I would like to know if my tough process in approaching this problem is correct.

Comment: But your conclusion doesn't agree with your working. Can you check that you don't have a typo? If I'm not mistaken, $f$ is continuous on $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x=0 \text{ or } y\ne 0\}$.

Comment: Yes I think I wrote it wrong, $f$ is continuous in $\Re^2 \setminus \{(x,0), x \ne 0\}$

Comment: By the way, it is customary to use "Blackboard bold" to denote $\Bbb R, \Bbb N$ etc. You get this with \Bbb R, \Bbb N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split up the analysis into cases.

Case 1: If $y=0$, then $f(x,y)=0$ by definition.

Case 2: If $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$, then

$$\Big|f(x,y)\Big|=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,y)} \Big|x\sin\frac{1}{y}\Big|\leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,y)}\Big|x\Big|$$

since $|\sin\frac{1}{y}|\leq 1$. In this case, $f(x,y)\to 0$ since $x=0$.

Case 3: If $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, then

$$\Big|f(x,y)\Big|=\lim_{(x,y) \to (x,y)} \Big|x\sin\frac{1}{y}\Big|\leq \lim_{(x,y) \to (x,y)}\Big|x\Big|$$

since $|\sin\frac{1}{y}|\leq 1$. However, as $x\neq 0$, $f(x,y)\not \to 0$. Therefore, $f(x,y)$ will be greater or less than zero depending on the value of $x$.

So, the function $f(x,y)$ isn't continuous at $(x,0)$.

It is true that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(x,0)$ provided that $\{(x,y)\in
\mathbb R^2∣(x=0~ \text{and}~ y≠0)~ \text{or}~y=0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use sequences: Fix $0\neq x\in \mathbb R$. There are sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ such that $y_n\to 0$ and $z_n\to 0$ and such that $\sin(1/y_n)=1$ and $\sin(1/z_n)=-1$ (why?). Then, $\alpha_n=(x,y_n)\to (x,0)$ and $\beta_n=(x,z_n)\to (x,0)$ but $f(\alpha_n)\to x$ and $f(\beta_n)\to -x$ so $f$ is not continuous at $(x,0).$

The case $x=0$ is even easier.

Comment: I'm not familiar with sequences

Comment: Then take any neighborhood $N_{(x,0)}$ of $(x,0)\in \mathbb R^2$ and show that there are points $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $N$ for which $f(\alpha)=x$ and $f(\beta)=-x$ so $f$ can not be continuous there. It is basically the same argument as the one in my answer.

Comment: @Matematleta: That's not right. It should be $f(\alpha)=x$ and $f(\beta)=-x$.

Comment: @TonyK yes thanks.